# Lemma/rule to allow substitution in universally quantified variable (Isabelle)

Tags: isabelle, quantifiers

I have a goal which looks something like `"\<forall>x. \<exists>y.\<forall>(z::real). P x y z"`. Is there a rule which immediately allows me to conclude `"\<forall>x. \<exists>y.\<forall>(z::real). P x y (z-2)"`? If there isn't, I'd appreciate general advice on how to prove this type of goal.

I know I can prove it by using lots of `allI`,`exI`, `allE`,`exE`, but it seems like there must be a quick and simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in Isabelle2016-1-RC2:

```
lemma
  assumes "∀x. ∃y.∀(z::real). P x y z"
  shows "∀x. ∃y.∀(z::real). P x y (z-2)"
using assms by force
```

You can use the `try0` command to give you a list of proof methods that are able to solve the goal.

Comment: This is helpful. Unfortunately, the thing I really want to prove is slightly more complicated and doesn't work using this.

Comment: You can try peeling off one quantifier after the other and doing only the minimum amount of work to aid automation.